# idHTTP Returns <!DOCTYPE html> error

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-7, indy, http-get

What I'm trying to achieve is return some data from a web page using idhtp1.GET 
When I do:

```pascal
sGeo := RemoveWhiteSpace('http://www.robin-william.net/Osiris/geo.php?ip=IPHERE');
redt1.Lines.Add(idhtpGeo.Get(sGeo));
```

it works perfectly, but once I do this:

```
sGeo := RemoveWhiteSpace('http://www.robin-william.net/Osiris/geo.php?ip=' + sData);
```

(added sData) it gives me the error DOCTYPE html.

[image]

Here is a part of the source:

```pascal
procedure TfrmMap.GetGeo(sData : string);
begin
  try
  idhtpGeo.ConnectTimeout := 5000;
  idhtpGeo.HandleRedirects := True;
  sGeo := RemoveWhiteSpace('http://www.robin-william.net/Osiris/geo.php?ip=' + sData);
  redt1.Lines.Add(sGeo);
  redt1.Lines.Add(idhtpGeo.Get(sGeo));
  except
    MessageDlg('Failed to load Geo Data!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

sData is just the IP. I also tried using the SynaCode unit to encode the URL(sGeo), and it didn't give me any errors but the data being returned wasn't correct.

The encoded URL looks as follows:

```
http://www.robin-william.net/Osiris/geo.php?ip=88.106.170.45%0A
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Indy are you using? I am not able to reproduce the problem using the latest Indy 10 SVN snapshot. `Get()` returns successfully, even if the IP parameter is malformed. Even if the error did occur, the `<!DOCTYPE html>` should not be in the exception's `Message` property (which the debugger notification shows), it should be in the exception's `ErrorMessage` property instead (which the debugger notification does not show).

Comment: If I'm not mistaking im using indy 7. Not 100% sure though. 
And yes the message that it displayed is strange, I tried Googleing it but got no results. But the problem was that sData just needed to be trimmed.

Comment: There is no Indy 7. Delphi 6 shipped with Indy 8 (I forget what version of Indy shipped with Delphi 7). Before 8, Indy was known as WinShoes instead.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am ineed using indy 10

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found the problem. Just had to trim the string named sData.

Comment: Perhaps better to set sData correctly to begin with